# format pandas column with strings and numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, which consists of numbers and strings. It looks something like this:

```
Column1   Column2
name1     12.4
name2     13
name3     -
name4     0.2
```

I want to format Column2 so that all numbers are formated with one digit after the comma. The problem is, that all elements in Column2 are strings.

I tried to convert them to numeric values with pd.to_numeric

```
dfRW[dfRW.columns[1]] = pd.to_numeric(dfRW[dfRW.columns[1]])
```

However because of the hyphen "-" it results in an error (which I kind of expected). So I found that I can include errors='ignore', and then it works.

The next step would be to use .format to get the digits, so I tried:

```
dfRW[dfRW.columns[1]] = pd.to_numeric(dfRW[dfRW.columns[1]], errors='ignore').map('${:,.2f}'.format)
```

but again the hyphen makes problems.

The expected result would be:

```
Column1   Column2
name1     12.4
name2     13.0
name3     -
name4     0.2
```

I have some workaround ideas (like sorting and then only formating the numbers above the rows with hyphens), but I first wanted to check if there is a function that I don't know, which would solve my problem.

**Edit:**
I just checked the datatype of the elements in my dataframe, and they are dtype "object", in case this helps with solving the problem of the AttributError: Can only use .str accessor with string values.

Edit2:
Sorry, I am constantly switching between ',' and '.' as comma. As mentioned in the title I have "numbers" =floats, and string. I changed the numbers in the tables above to the correct form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `,` to `.`, so possible use `to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` for missing values for `-` (and another no numbers values) and then use `map` with `if-else` for processing `NaN`s:

```
f = lambda x: '${:.1f}'.format(x).replace('.', ',') if pd.notna(x) else '-'
dfRW.iloc[:, 1]=pd.to_numeric(dfRW.iloc[:, 1], errors='coerce').map(f)

print (dfRW)
  Column1 Column2
0   name1   $12,4
1   name2   $13,0
2   name3       -
3   name4    $0,2
```

If use `errors='ignore'` and some error no converting, get same ouput like input.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use `float()` with a string containing `,`? Or maybe another Python built-in function? Because traversing the entire string to replace commas seems inefficient with really large inputs

Comment: @Cardstdani - `Is there any possibility to use float() with a string containing` - in python not

Comment: This looks promesing, however it results in an error for me: "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: @Carina - Can you test edited answer? Removed `.str.replace(',','.')`

Comment: How do I convert the resulting strings back into floats? Do I need another lambda function for this, or is there a quicker way? .astype(float) obviously doesn't work, because I first need to switch from ',' back to '.'

Comment: @Carina - Then use `dfRW.iloc[:, 1]=pd.to_numeric(dfRW.iloc[:, 1].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 1):

You can add `,0` to those value which doesn't contain `,` and is not `-`

```py
m1 = df['Column2'].eq('-')
m2 = df['Column2'].str.contains(',')

df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].mask(~m1 & ~m2, df['Column2']+',0')
```

```
print(df)

  Column1 Column2
0   name1    12,4
1   name2    13,0
2   name3       -
3   name4     0,2
```

Comment: I like this one, however I forgot to mention that I have several dataframes, and not all of them contain a '-'. So if I am applying this to a column without a hyphen, it results in an error, because of the m1. I guess I could use an if statement to catch this case, but is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry, on my second try without the attempt of changing your code into an if statement I get AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! This is from simply copying your code and changing the column names to the names of my actual column names: dfRW[dfRW.columns[1]]

Comment: @Carina If your column contains int, you need `astype(str)` first.

Comment: Thanks, that gets rid of the error. I also changed ',' to '.', as my numbers are separated by '.' (I edited my post), however then m2 is true everywhere. If I leave it as ',' it figures out that there are no ',' and therefore adds the ,0 everywhere resulting in numbers such as "0.4,0". I don't understand why it finds '.' everywhere, even when they are not there.

Comment: @Carina Default `regex` for` str.contains` is True, you need turn it to False.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply a function to the `Column2` values. First, you replace commas with dots to be able to use `float()` function and format the result with only 2 decimals into a list comprehension:

```
l = ["0,2", "13", "12,4"]

l = ['{:,.2f}'.format(float(i.replace(",", "."))) for i in l]
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
['0.20', '13.00', '12.40']
```

Comment: Though this answer does not contain everything I need, I tried it as a first step, but I get AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'. Also please note that I have a Pandas Dataframe, and not a list.